# What is the difference between $_REQUEST and file_get_contents('php://input');

Tags: php, angularjs

I was just experimenting with AngularJS and am fairly new to it. I am making an http call to my php service using `$http`. I noticed that the data that I am passing while making the post call was not getting read at the php side - I tried `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and it just showed an empty Array. The same call when made with jQuery's `$.ajax` however showed that the data had passed across.

I then found a Stackoverflow post where someone had asked for the data to be read as `file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of with `$_REQUEST`. I tried that, and I was able to get the data now using AngularJS's `$http`. However, when I tried to make a Get call with AngularJS $http method, the `file_get_contents('php://input');` shows `NULL` whereas `$_REQUEST` shows the data has passed.

I am confused as to what exactly these two are and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php vs. http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a GET request, you're sending all data as part of the url. But when you send a request with data that is not part of the url (using the `data` property of `$http`), Angular sends the request data as JSON in the request payload. However, PHP populates the POST request variable from a url encoded string of key-value pairs having the request content type of `x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can [send data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded from Angular](http://jeecookbook.blogspot.ca/2013/03/angularjs-trick-posting-data-using-url.html), but I'd stick with JSON.